# How to create a new smaller array from a larger array, taking the average of the old array's elements?

Tags: python

Lets say I have an array of length `n`:

```
a = np.arange(1, 20, 0.5).tolist()
```

I want to create a new array of a smaller size of length `m`, where `m < n`, and fill this array with the average values of the older array. For example, array `a` is 38 in length, but I want to create array `b` of length 15. The first element of `b` would be the average value of the first two or three elements in `a`.

Another example: if I had a vector of length 1491 and wanted to reshape it to an array of length 200, 1491 cannot be perfectly divided by 200 right? The same is true if array a was 4442 but array b was still 200, a different number of values will be needed to get the average values to put into b this time.

Is there a suitable way to do this?

Comment: Your explanation is pretty vague. Could you be more specific? Are you trying to say that each value in the array b is a average of any random amount of values from a? Also how are you deciding the length of the array b?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to say that each value in the array b is a average of any random amount of values from a, because a could be any length (1491, 4442). For example, if I had a vector of length 1491 and wanted to reshape it to an array of length 200, 1491 cannot be perfectly divided by 200 right? The same is true if array a was 4442 but array b was still 200, a different number of values will be needed to get the average values to put into b this time. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: @Woj Updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66175978/941531) with more advanced computations for the case when a size is not evenly divisible by b size.

Answer (score 3):

If for example you have array of size 20 `a = np.arange(20)` then you can reshape it to new 2D shape `a = a.reshape(10, 2)`, second dimension says how many consequent numbers you want to average, in my example you average each 2 consequent numbers, then you compute average reducing 2nd dimension `a = a.mean(axis = 1)` thus having resulting array of size 10. Full code:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtBCoAgEEX3nWKWChFp6w7zF1IuHIfRIE9vEkSrz3uPL62embfeY5KslfhK0giFWCbQPmaBgo9g/Gon0cjVwL4Ji4ZyQoJx60z@kymADe5YBrn/0vsD)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(20)
print(a)
a = a.reshape(10, 2)
a = a.mean(axis = 1)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
[ 0.5  2.5  4.5  6.5  8.5 10.5 12.5 14.5 16.5 18.5]
```

---

If you for some reason have such b size that a size is not divisible evenly by b size, then you can do next thing - some elements on the left group in blocks of size `a_size // b_size + 1` and some on the right in blocks of size `a_size // b_size`. Next code does this computation (example input a size is 18, desired b size is 5):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHvasMgFMW/@xQX9iHaZSlhDEphT1JKuQbXhBkjaqHdy2dXzb@NLSBJfudc77lqH6EdzOs4dr0dXABz6@0D0IOxDOGdXhU6NFfF64Ng8uK7L0X4jVnXmcAL8hQloGBPIDUJWCXHfg/ZS1zDMziSNmAHXEZci6TtptrVMP/Ay1SWPOzvFhv40752JUEvkachYu5UVUIhV5Y/iWn1ERLRJQN6Ctdd20xcLNFD83lZTHmeha9eqQVD7xUd7j@Dz@kZaooUQ@PpuPWeCZ@24Hgmb/TpyinfolVczxGoW9rCLZLLIWS@zmYwDQZlaHFOG/QKDcd750muRQzwCwkxn5zMAwk2jt8)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(18)
b_size = 5
print('a =', a)
# bl = a.size // b_size
# l + r = b_size
# l * (bl + 1) + r * bl = a_size
# l = a_size - b_size * bl
bl = a.size // b_size
l = a.size - b_size * bl
r = b_size - l
print('a_size =', a.size, 'b_size =', b_size, 'left =', l,
    'right =', r, 'block_left =', bl + 1, 'block_right =', bl)
assert l * (bl + 1) + r * bl == a.size
al, ar = a[:l * (bl + 1)], a[l * (bl + 1):]
al = al.reshape(l, bl + 1)
ar = ar.reshape(r, bl)
b = np.concatenate((al.mean(axis = 1), ar.mean(axis = 1)))
print('b =', b)
```

Output:

```
a = [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
a_size = 18 b_size = 5 left = 3 right = 2 block_left = 4 block_right = 3
b = [ 1.5  5.5  9.5 13.  16. ]
```

Comment: What if, for example, array a was of length 1491, and array b was of length 200? If the length of b was not perfectly divisible by the length  of a? Is there a way automatically determine the number of values from a needed to get the average values to put in b?

Comment: @Woj There multiple solutions to your task, imagine a was of size 5, having elements `0 1 2 3 4` and b is suppose size of 2, then how to decide what is the right way? One way is to split `0 1 2` and `3 4` another way is to split `0 1` and `2 3 4`, which one to choose?

Comment: I see. I suppose the way to choose is not important to my objective. It could be either way. Let's say though, I wanted to do it the second way (`0 1` and `2 3 4`), how would the code look?

Comment: @Woj Just updated my answer with 2nd part with more advanced computation. Basically if a size is not evenly divisible by b size then some blocks on the left I do with size `a_size // b_size + 1` and remaining on the right I do with size `a_size // b_size`.